# how to double click web object in VBA

Tags: vba, web, automation

I am automating a web process with VBA. I go find an object on a webpage using

```
IE.document.getelementsbytagname
```

etc.. Once that object is found, you can single click using

```
 objElement.click
```

The question is, how do I double click?? All my searches have come up with nothing. I thought dblClick or doubleClick would do the trick, but those are invalid methods. I tried a workaround by using

```
objElement.click
sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

to click and then hitting enter would open the link, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this working:

```
objElement.click
objElement.FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @tbodt  the answer I submitted is the answer to my question.

Comment: Oh. Sorry about that.