# How do I navigate to another page by double-clicking on an HTML table row?

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am only able to highlight the row but I am not able to double click in the TR in order to fire the event and to go to the next page.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Set table = webpage.Document.getElementsByClassName("grid-mvc")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")(0).getElementsByTagName("table")(0).getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)
'Double Click on row


For Each RowElement In table.getElementsByClassName("grid-cell")
MsgBox RowElement.innerText
    RowElement.Click
    RowElement.Focus

     RowElement.FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
      RowElement.Focus
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"



     RowElement.FireEvent ("ondbclick")
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"
     RowElement.FireEvent ("ondbclick")
     RowElement.FireEvent ("onmousedown")
       'RowElement.dispatchEvent ("ondblclick")
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"

RowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")(1).Click




    If Trim(RowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText) = Value Then


 MsgBox RowElement.textContent
RowElement.getElementsByTagName("td")(0).Click



End If
Next
```

HTML CODE:

```
<TBODY>
  <TR class="grid-row ">
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="FacilityID">49343</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="SubBrand">QQ</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="PMSType">OnQ</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="PMSAccountingID">ORNA       </TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="PMSIDDesc"></TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="AccountingIDFullAcct">
      <DIV class="GLAccount">99 90700 USD</DIV></TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="AccountDescription">
      <DIV title="Charitable Contributions      " 
      class="GLAccountDesc">Charitable Contributions      </DIV></TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="AccountingID">2861</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="StartDate">12/7/2018</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="EndDate">12/31/2078</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="CodeBlockSpecific">No</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="SystemDefault">No</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="PermissionLevel">Permitted</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="UserID">MERE</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="LastUpdateTime">
      <DIV class="LastUpdateTime">12/7/2018 11:02:00 PM</DIV></TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="MgmtGroup">Franchised</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="AcctType">Franchised</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="FinSys">
      <DIV title="Franchise" class="FinancialSystem">Franchise</DIV></TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="Inncode">SEACU</TD>
    <TD class="grid-cell" data-name="HotelName">
      <DIV title="The Charter Hotel  Seattle, WA" class="HotelName">The Charter 
      Hotel  Seattle, WA</DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<DIV class="grid-footer">
<DIV class="grid-itemscount"><SPAN class="grid-itemscount-label">Total 
Count:</SPAN>                 <SPAN class="grid-itemscount-caption">1</SPAN>     
        </DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id="MappingSearchFacilityIdDialog"></DIV>
<DIV id="ApplyBrandDefaultMappingDialog"></DIV>
<SCRIPT>
```

Comment: which row do you actually need to click on?

Comment: in the first one with the value 49343 i tried all the code i put above but it only gets highlighted also the row it does not have a href attribute

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are only using Click(). it will not do double click and not fire any event.

To fire any event, You can try to use code like below.

```html
objElement.click
objElement.FireEvent "ondblclick", 1, 2
```

Reference:

[how to double click web object in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855904/how-to-double-click-web-object-in-vba)

[Re: Perform double click on html element, vb6](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?802943-Perform-double-click-on-html-element-vb6)

Comment: I already tried to use  the  code that you provided but it did not worked  so the only work arround i think in orther to move to the next page is to composing the URL:

Comment: You can also try to add button or link in that table cell and try to click it using VBA code may help to solve the issue.